# How to know which button is clicked when there are multiple buttons (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table inside a functional component. Each row in the table has an edit button at the end of the row. When I click an Edit button it applies the changes to all the edit buttons. How do I know which button is clicked and apply changes only to that? (I have a large number of rows so I cannot create a state for each button)

[Here is a link to my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-brook-rlzkf)

Comment: Please show the relevant button rendering code in the question itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way you can do is keep track of row index on the state. For example, provide `id` to the button, which is equal to index of the row

```
 <Button id={index} type="button" onClick={e => this.handleEdit(e)}>
```

and in your `handleEdit` function

```
  handleEdit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showbutton: true,
      showButtonIndex: Number(e.target.id)
    });
  };
```

This way you have a index of the clicked row in the state and you can change your logic to show your `<Edit />` component as

```
{this.state.showbutton && (this.state.showButtonIndex === index) && <Edit />}
```

I am assuming, you are allowing only one row to edit at a time.

Working code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-brook-5sshe?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what the desired behavior of the button is, however, it seems that this is the relevant code for creating the buttons

```
  handleEdit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showbutton: true
    });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.names);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Names: </h2>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {this.state.names.map((name, index) => {
            return (
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td> {name} </td>
                  <td>
                    <Button type="button" onClick={e => this.handleEdit(e)}>
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                  {this.state.showbutton && <Edit />}
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            );
          })}
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

You can see in the this.states.map() function that there is an index parameter that gets bound.  You can use this to keep track of which button is calling the function and passing that into the function as such

```
handleEdit = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({
      showbutton: true
    });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.names);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Names: </h2>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {this.state.names.map((name, index) => {
            return (
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td> {name} </td>
                  <td>
                    <Button type="button" onClick={e => this.handleEdit(e, index)}>
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                  {this.state.showbutton && <Edit />}
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            );
          })}
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The example just prints the id of the button that clicked it.  You can utilize this in whatever way necessary to uniquely identify the buttons.

The code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-thunder-hni18)

Comment: this seems to be correct but doesnt give me the desired output. I guess, a state managing the index needs to be added

Comment: If you click on any of the buttons, it will give you a number 0-2 as the index of the button, as there are three buttons, there are 3 indexes.  You can implement this however you want.  I personally believe that it is much more efficient than the other answer as you aren't creating an id for each button.  I don't understand what you mean by it doesn't have the desired behavior.

Comment: I tried running this but it displays the string "Edit Name" for all the buttons when I click even 1 button; so the output is the same as output in the question.

Comment: Yes, I put it in the console using `console.log`, you would have to open the console and see the output

Comment: So when I call the Edit component; should I pass the index as well ? as I want to see the string only in front of the button I click not on all buttons

Comment: If you wanted to have a string appear in that area then you would have to identify it with something such as an ID.  If that is your intention, then the other answer would be better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I make some changes [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-golick-zgm34)

1. Convert the state to an array of objects with showbutton in every id.
2. Change the function to handle extra parameter id

Answer (score 0):

```
function Lists() {
    const handleClick = (button) => {
        console.log(button.target);
    };

    return (
        <section className={css.actionList}>
            <div className={css.itemActive} onClick={handleClick}>
                Posts
            </div>
            <div className={css.itemActive} onClick={handleClick}>
                Comments
            </div>
            <div className={css.itemActive} onClick={handleClick}>
                Liked Posts
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

I assume that you won't use props and pass to children elements state of click. Hope it helps